# Why does this html table definition not validate?

Tags: html, w3c-validation, html-table

I'm getting this W3C HTML validation error:

```
end tag for "table" which is not finished
```

for this code:

```
<table id="myTable">
</table>
```

This is my DOCTYPE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

**I thought that table definition was perfectly fine!?**

Comment: It looks OK to me.  Is this the actual code that is throwing the error?

Answer (score 6):

If you look at the [XHTML 1.0 Strict DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html#a_dtd_XHTML-1.0-Strict), it specifies that a table *requires* at least one of `TR` OR `TBODY`:

```
<!ELEMENT table
     (caption?, (col*|colgroup*), thead?, tfoot?, (tbody+|tr+))>
<!ELEMENT caption  %Inline;>
<!ELEMENT thead    (tr)+>
<!ELEMENT tfoot    (tr)+>
<!ELEMENT tbody    (tr)+>
<!ELEMENT colgroup (col)*>
<!ELEMENT col      EMPTY>
<!ELEMENT tr       (th|td)+>
<!ELEMENT th       %Flow;>
<!ELEMENT td       %Flow;>
```

The `TR`, in its turn, requires at least one of `TH` or `TD`.

The `+` sign after an element name means it should appear *at least once*.

Comment: I was looking for that in the spec, and you beat me to it.

Comment: The OP's document doesn't use HTML 4.0.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen XHTML 1 and HTML 4 use the same basic specs, I'll have to go look in the XHTML 1 DTD, but the only real difference is some syntax specifications in XHTML.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen - fair point. Answer updated for XHTML 1.0 DTD.

Comment: Same basic thing: http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xhtml1-20000126/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd search for `<!ELEMENT table` just like in the HTML4 version. at least one `tbody` and `tr` are required.

Comment: @zzzzBov - indeed. Matthew was right however, so I updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I believe there should be a tr and td  tags inside a table to validate. It's the same when you close a head tag without including a title tag

Comment: I'm not getting this warning when I do `<table></table>`

Answer (score 3):

A XHTML 1.0 table is required to have at least a `tbody` or a `tr` child.  See [the DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html#a_dtd_XHTML-1.0-Strict), specifically the [table element](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html#dtdentry_xhtml1-strict.dtd_table):

```
<!ELEMENT table
     (caption?, (col*|colgroup*), thead?, tfoot?, (tbody+|tr+))>
```

Note the last part.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://validator.w3.org/docs/errors.html

73: end tag for X which is not finished

Most likely, you nested tags and closed them in the wrong order. For example `<p><em>`.
`</p>` is not acceptable, as `<em>` must be closed before `<p>`. Acceptable nesting is:

```
<p><em>...</em></p>
```

Another possibility is that you used an element which requires a child element that you did not include. Hence the parent element is "not finished", not complete. For instance, in HTML the  element must contain a  child element, lists require appropriate list items (`<ul>` and `<ol>` require `<li>`; `<dl>` requires `<dt>` and `<dd>`), and so on.

You need at least one `<tr>` inside your table.